# How to open a Python pickle file, append to it, save it, and close it?

Tags: python, pickle

Here is my code:

```
 import pickle


 class User:
     def __init__(self, username, password):
         self.username = username
         self.password = password

     def set_password(self):
         self.password = input("Enter NEW password > ")

     def __get_password(self):
         return self.password

     def __get_username(self):
         return self.username

     def change_password(self):
         my_password = input("Enter your CURRENT password > ")
         if my_password == User.__get_password(self):
             self.set_password()
         else:
             print("Please try again")

     def display_details(self):
         print()
         print("Username and password")
         print("---------------------")
         print("username is: ", User.__get_username(self))
         print("password is: ", User.__get_password(self))
         print()

     def __repr__(self):
         return f'username: {self.username}'


 users = [User("MichaelPalin", "P4rr0t"), User("EricIdle", "M0nty"), User("TerryJones", "Pyth0n")]

 try:
     foo = pickle.load(open("users.pickle", "rb"))
 except (OSError, IOError) as f:
     foo = 3
     pickle.dump(foo, open("users.pickle", "wb"))

 # with open('users.pickle', 'wb') as f:
 #     pickle.dump(users, f)


 def find_user(name):
     for user in users:
         if user.username == name:
             return user


 def add_user():
     user = input("Enter NEW user > ")
     password = input(f"Enter password for {user} > ")
     users.append(User(user, password))


 def delete_user():
     delete_user = input("Enter the user you wish to remove > ")
     user = find_user(delete_user)
     if user:
         users.remove(user)
         print('done')
     else:
         print(f'user {delete_user} not found')


 def change_password():
     my_password = input("Enter your CURRENT password > ")
     change_password()


 def display_users():
     for user in users:
         print(user)


 def invalid_entry():  # Response for invalid entries to menu.
     print("Invalid entry, please try again")
     print()


 def menu():  # Display menu, prompt for and accept keyboard choice
     print("Please select one of the following:")
     print()
     print("Enter a if you want to add a new user")
     print("Enter d if you want to delete a user")
     print("Enter f if you want to find a user")
     print("Enter c if you want to change your password")
     print("Enter u if you want to display a list of users")
     print("Enter q if you want to Quit")
     choice = input("")
     return choice


 while True:
     menu_choice = menu()
     if menu_choice.lower() == "a":
         add_user()
     elif menu_choice.lower() == "d":
         delete_user()
     elif menu_choice.lower() == "f":
         find_user()
     elif menu_choice.lower() == "c":
         change_password()
     elif menu_choice.lower() == 'u':
         display_users()
     elif menu_choice.lower() == "q":
         print("Goodbye")
         with open('users.pickle', 'wb') as f:
             pickle.dump(users, f)
             quit()
     else:
         invalid_entry()
```

It's not working properly though, as the pickle file is being overwritten every time the program runs. I'm guessing the culprit is the `users` line, but I don't know how to resolve the problem, if that's the case. I tried moving the entire line to the bottom of the `try` section, aligned with the `pickle.dump` line, but that just threw an error:

> NameError: name 'users' is not defined

Can someone help me please? I've been trying to do this for about 2 weeks now and I'm getting increasingly frustrated. I've looked at so many related tutorials on the web that many of the links I'm seeing are now purple, but I just can't seem to work out how to write the code to create the correct logical flow.

I think the logic should probably be:

1) Does file exist?
If Y - do nothing
If N - create it with sample data

2) Does the user want to create a new login?
If Y - append the login to the file
If N - do nothing

Comment: A pickle is an oblique structure, the idea that you could append something without modifying the head is incorrect.

Comment: @tripleee - I'm afraid I don't know what you mean by that. I tried Googling "A pickle is an oblique structure" but am still none the wiser for it.

Comment: he meant that a pickle is not a text file that you can just append to, its a binary object that you have to rewrite, which is what you do

Comment: @Nullman - I see, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue I found is that you arent actually using the loaded pickle data in these lines:

```
users = [User("MichaelPalin", "P4rr0t"), User("EricIdle", "M0nty"), User("TerryJones", "Pyth0n")]

 try:
     foo = pickle.load(open("users.pickle", "rb"))
 except (OSError, IOError) as f:
     foo = 3
     pickle.dump(foo, open("users.pickle", "wb"))
```

You load the file into `foo` but never use it and your exception doesn't make much sense, try changing that block into the following:

```
 try:
     users = pickle.load(open("users.pickle", "rb"))
 except (OSError, IOError) as f:
     users = [User("MichaelPalin", "P4rr0t"), User("EricIdle", "M0nty"), User("TerryJones", "Pyth0n")]
     pickle.dump(foo, open("users.pickle", "wb"))
```

Now you will try to load the pre-made file, and on failure generate a default

Comment: THANK YOU!!! FINALLY cracked it! Hallelujah!! I was actually not far off with trying to fit the `users` line into that block, but I wasn't doing it right though. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
try:
    users = pickle.load(open("users.pickle", "rb"))
except (OSError, IOError) as f:
    foo = 3
    print("except")
    pickle.dump(users, open("users.pickle", "wb"))
```

also `quit()` outside with:

```
with open('users.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(users, f)
quit()
```

Comment: When giving an answer, try to give some explanations about why your solution answers the original poster's question. This will help other users quickly identify if your answer can also apply to their problem.